# In node.js --prof output, what is this strangely-named C++ function doing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, profiling, v8

I am profiling a heavily modified fork of [JS Interpreter](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter), running on node.js v12.12.0, using `--prof`, while it runs a short synthetic benchmark.  In the output from `node --prof-process, I see that 63% of the program's runtime is spent in C++:

```
 [Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   1503   35.6%   35.9%  JavaScript
   2658   63.0%   63.4%  C++
    119    2.8%    2.8%  GC
     30    0.7%          Shared libraries
     29    0.7%          Unaccounted
```

In particular, there is one single C++ function that accounts for 59% of the entire runtime:

```
 [C++]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
   2504   59.3%   59.8%  t __ZN4node9inspector8protocol11NodeRuntime14DispatcherImplD1Ev
     27    0.6%    0.6%  T node::native_module::NativeModuleEnv::CompileFunction(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)
     23    0.5%    0.5%  T _proc_set_dirty
     16    0.4%    0.4%  T __kernelrpc_vm_remap
      9    0.2%    0.2%  t __malloc_initialize
      9    0.2%    0.2%  T _thread_get_state
      8    0.2%    0.2%  T node::contextify::ContextifyContext::CompileFunction(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)
  ...
```

Unfortunately, it's not too obvious to me what `__ZN4node9inspector8protocol11NodeRuntime14DispatcherImplD1Ev` might be doing.

- The name suggests that it has something to do with the inspector protocol, but I am not using the `--inspect` command line flag nor attempting to attach to the running process using the inspector.
- I can't seem to find any file in node.js sources that contains both the strings "NodeRuntime" and "DispatcherImpl".
- It seems to be called from several different places, most usually recursively from itself (list trimmed to show mainly top-level entries), but the named JavaScript functions don't have any obvious commonality:

```
 [Bottom up (heavy) profile]:
  Note: percentage shows a share of a particular caller in the total
  amount of its parent calls.
  Callers occupying less than 1.0% are not shown.

   ticks parent  name
   2504   59.3%  t __ZN4node9inspector8protocol11NodeRuntime14DispatcherImplD1Ev
   1287   51.4%    t __ZN4node9inspector8protocol11NodeRuntime14DispatcherImplD1Ev
    785   61.0%      LazyCompile: *intrp.Object.defineProperty /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/interpreter.js:4477:51
    226   17.6%      LazyCompile: *intrp.UserFunction.instantiateDeclarations /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/interpreter.js:4840:66
     67    5.2%      LazyCompile: *intrp.Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/interpreter.js:4455:61
     34    2.6%      t __ZN4node9inspector8protocol11NodeRuntime14DispatcherImplD1Ev
     22    1.7%      LazyCompile: *stepFuncs_.MemberExpression /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/interpreter.js:6582:42
    278   11.1%    LazyCompile: *Interpreter.run /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/interpreter.js:290:37
    140    5.6%    LazyCompile: *stepFuncs_.Identifier /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/interpreter.js:6494:36
    121    4.8%    LazyCompile: *intrp.UserFunction.instantiateDeclarations /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/interpreter.js:4840:66
     91    3.6%    LazyCompile: ~runBench /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/tests/interpreter_bench.js:37:18
     79    3.2%    LazyCompile: *intrp.UserFunction.call /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/interpreter.js:4782:47
     65    2.6%    LazyCompile: *Interpreter.getBoundNames_ /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/interpreter.js:2907:48
     62    2.5%    LazyCompile: *stepFuncs_.CallExpression /Users/cpcallen/src/CodeCity/server/interpreter.js:6039:40
```

I wondered if it might actually be the garbage collector, but using `--trace-gc` shows that GC is taking much less than 10% of total runtime.

How can I figure out what this C++ function is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding `DispatcherImpl` isn't hard: https://github.com/nodejs/node/search?q=dispatcherimpl&unscoped_q=dispatcherimpl leads straight to https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/5aaa7fee2e4a075d9123b885f9e8cda3de2a780a/tools/inspector_protocol/templates/TypeBuilder_cpp.template#L218. But that probably isn't what you're really looking for...

There was a bug in the `--prof` system for a while where C++ ticks would get attributed to the wrong function -- looks like you might be running into that. It's been [fixed in V8 recently](https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/commit/58b45cca2f91fd3ae25715c20406d01a50722918), but the fix hasn't rolled into a Node release yet.

As a workaround, on Linux, you can use `perf` to profile C++ code [1], while still using `--prof` for JavaScript; JavaScript ticks as well as the C++/JavaScript distribution should be reliably correct in `--prof`'s output. On other platforms there should be equivalent generic profiling techniques.

[1] For details, read the man page. I typically use something like:

```
perf record -e cycles -F 10000 <executable and arguments>
perf report -M intel
```

Comment: This is extremely helpful, thanks.  I happen to be on macOS, but it looks like that was affected as well despite the commit describing the problem being "bugs in `--prof/linux-tick-processor`".

Comment: Unfortunately the output of `perf report` isn't exceedingly informative; the top function listed is `Builtins_LoadIC_Megamorphic` which accounts for a mere 6.75% of the samples.  Perhaps that's correct—it makes more sense than 60+% of CPU being taken up in a single C++ function—but it doesn't provide any obvious avenues for major performance wins.